# Blackberry JDE component Package 4.6.1 not visible after disabling Vista UAC

Tags: blackberry, windows-vista, blackberry-jde

I'm running Eclipse version 3.4.1 on a Windows Vista machine. Currently I've installed:

```
BB JDE plug-in for eclipse ver.1.0.0.67
BB Component Pack 4.6.1
BB component pack 4.5.0.16
```

Usually I work with the UAC enabled and everything was fine till when I needed to sign the application. Everytime I selected the "Request Signatures" function I got an error message relative to a directory with a random name that cannot be created.  Reading the BB forum I discovered that UAC creates this problem so I disabled it.

The result: exactly like in the Admin Mode, Eclipse lost many plug-ins, like Subclipse, so I had to re-install them. My problem is that even  after I installed component pack 4.6.1, as you can see in the list above, the package is not visible in BB installed components.  Only the standard 4.5.0 is there. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of issues with BlackBerry dev tools on Vista and Windows 7 when installing in the default "Program Files" directory.  Apparently some of these tools try to write files into their install directory which Vista/Win7 doesn't like.

The workaround is to make sure you change the install path for your BlackBerry dev tools - for example instead of installing to "C:\Program Files\Research in Motion" install to "C:\rim"

I'm not sure if this is the problem you're encountering, but it might be worth a try.